# sort an ArrayList with multiple conditions

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

say i have an array list `MyArrayList<MYObject>`

myObject class looks like :

```
public class myObject
{
      String name;
      Int age;
      String : city;
}
```

and my dummy data looks like this :

```
name : martin ,  age : 20 , city : NY
name : felix ,  age : 19 , city : LA
name : brian ,  age : 21 , city : NY
name : brian ,  age : 19 , city : NY
```

now i wanna sort **myArraylist** (which have the above data in it) in this order -

```
name : felix , lastname : 19 , city : LA
name : brian , lastname : 21 , city : NY
name : martin , lastname : 20 , city : NY
name : brian , lastname : 19 , city : NY
```

as you can see that the above data is sorted in two ways - firstly by **cities** then again by **age** so this is what i wanna do , i wanna sort an arrayList by an order then again i wanna sort in another order by keeping the first order

anyone knows how can i do it ?? please let me know then

if my question is not clear enough then let me know i'll fix it

Comment: Use orderby...its a stable sort so the second time you sort it will preserve order of the first sort

Comment: so you mean i should do the first sorting then on second sorting i have to use `orderby` ??

Comment: Yea that would work

Comment: According java the default sort for collections is stable so you can just double sort and it should do the trick.  I quickly glanced at this and thought it was c#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a Comparator to first compare by city, then by age. Something like this:

```
Comparator<MyObject> comparator = new Comparator<MyObject>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(final MyObject o1, final MyObject o2){
       if(!o1.getCity().equals(o2.getCity())){
          return o1.getCity().compareTo(o2.getCity());
       }else{
          return o1.getAge().compareTo(o2.getAge());
        }
    }
  };

Collections.sort(myArrayList,comparator);
```

**Edit:**

I used the "compareTo" method of the Integer class, which you can't call on an `int` primitive type. If you use `int` for the age, you could just write out an if statement for the comparison.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options, which are essentially equivalent:

- perform two sorts with a [stable sort algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Stable_sorts): first by age, then by city. A stable sort algorithm is a sorting algorithm that maintains the relative order of two elements `A` and `B` if they are equivalent under the current `<` function. This way, if you first sort by age, when you sort again by city and two elements have the same city, their relative order will be determined by the input order, so they will be sorted by age.
- perform a single sort with a compare function that says that `A < B` whenever `A.city != B.city && A.city < B.city` or `A.city = B.city && A.age > B.age`.

Notice that Java's `Collections.sort` is guaranteed to be stable, so pick whichever strategy better suits your needs.

Answer (score 2):

First of all classes should have a descriptive name and the class names should start with an upper case character. So I'll call your class Person

You need to create a custom `Comparator` to be used by the sort utility.

For a reusable solution you could use the [Bean Comparator](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/23/bean-comparator/) and the [Group Comparator](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/17/group-comparator/).

1. The `BeanComparator` allows you to sort on any property in the object
2. The `GroupComparator` allows you to combine multiple `Comparator` into a single `Comparator`.

So the basic logic would be:

```
BeanComparator city = new BeanComparator(Person.class, "getCity");
BeanComparator age = new BeanComparator(Person.class, "getAge");
GroupComparator gc = new GroupComparator(city, age);
Collections.sort(arrayList, gc);
```

Comment: `BeanComparator` and `GroupComparator` are two external classes that rely on reflection to carry out their job. Talk about over-engineering...

Comment: @akappa, only BeanComparator relies on reflection. The point of the two classes is to look at solutions for reusable code. Instead of creating Comparators for each property or combination of properties you can take advantage of these classes. A helpful solution if you ever need to let the user determine sort orders on any property. Thje BeanComparator shows how to create a simple Comparator than can then be used with the GroupComparator if you don't want to use reflection for the reasons given in the link.

Comment: introducing a new abstraction has some costs - in performance and readability - that must be offset by how much work you are abstracting away and how better you can convey your intentions. In this case, I'd say that the saving are marginal and the cost is substantial. Besides, what if I need to e.g. sort strings by length and not lexicographically? That's not supported by this abstraction. Or what if I want to sort in reverse order? I have to study your interface. If you use lambda functions as comparator, instead, what you get is concise code that immediately conveys its purpose.

Comment: @akappa, performance yes (and I noted that in the link). readability no as the 3 lines of code are simple and straight forward. You don't need to know the details of the class in order to use it, only the API, which you do for any class in the JDK. The class does support reverse order sorting, however I never implied that you would never have to write a custom Comparator again in your life. I simply stated these classes can prevent code bloat in the right situation. The whole point about programing is to create reusable code.

Comment: and @camickr dropped the mike

Comment: @camickr yes, it's three lines... but this is two: `Collections.sort(arrayList, (Person p1, Person p2) -> p2.getAge() - p1.getAge())); Collections.sort(arrayList, (Person p1, Person p2) -> p1.getName().compareTo(p2.getName()));`. I think this is both more straightforward (you are only using standard stuff and everything is in plain sight) and more efficient (the compiler might in-line the lambda function, avoiding indirect calls in a tight loop). That's why I think in this case introducing that abstraction is not worth the effort but, you know, programming is more an art than science :-)

Comment: @akappa, must admit I still haven't grasped lambda's and frankly would have no idea what that code does if you didn't tell me it somehow magically created a Comparator. I also don't understand why this wasn't your answer? `and more efficient`  - again why harp on that, I already stated the BeanComparator was not for efficiency but for reusability. Also, the GroupComparator would be more efficient then doing the sort twice.

Comment: `but this is two` - Again my comment was about readability and maintenance of the code, not absolute number of lines. You can write complex code containing multiple statements on a single line but to me it is not desirable. I could have written the code as a single statement and created the parameters of the GroupComparater with a single line of code. But I prefer to have individual variables for parameter to make it easier to read and debug.